# Delphi Berlin Data Breakpoint Invalid Address / Address for Data Breakpoint eludes me

Tags: delphi, debugging, delphi-10.1-berlin

Delphi 10.1 Berlin/ Windows 10 x64

My Google-Fu isn't finding this.

"Add Data Breakpoint" requires an address, how do I find it? The default address is $0, and I can't figure how to get the address of the variable I want to watch? I tried highlighting the variable, and then requesting data breakpoint, but no: nothing.

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose the variable is named `Foo`. Open the evaluate expression window (CTRL+F7) and evaluate `@Foo`. This is the address of the variable and what you need to supply for the data breakpoint.

Comment: Thank you @David! it works now, obvious now that I think about it :-) 417k REP isn't doing you justice :-)

Comment: Of course the debugger is helpful enough that you can directly write foo (even without the @).

Comment: Nope, thats why I asked the question, that doesn't work, clicking Run->Add Breakpoint->Data Breakpoint gives invalid address when just typing the variable... with @ however, it works

Comment: @chil - Yes, for some type of variables you need @, like pointers. The main point is, however, the debugger is able to resolve a variable by its name if it is in scope.